# Getting email on exception in any web application (Jboss)

Tags: java, exception, jboss

We are using Jboss 6 Final as our application server.

We have a requirement that on **any exception** on production server the application should send emails to mentioned email address . I have tried the log4j's SMTP appender which sends email and is running in error mode. But it is  quite  unfriendly because of its buffer size limitations and in the end we are getting flooded with emails .

I have also tried implementing java.beans.ExceptionListener but Jboss throws an exception that it does not inherit the marker interface java.util.EventListener. I want some suggestions . I am sure this is quite a common used case in web applications. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: This topic fits better into [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Any exception, or any untrapped exception?

Comment: Erm, I don't get it ... why don't you add then the java.beans.ExceptionListener to your implementation?

Comment: No , I didn't get your question. Are you asking me to put an implementation of ExceptionListener in web.xml under <listener></listener> tags ?

Comment: Also , its practically impossible to go in every class of the application and then add the exception listner instance.